# missing ';' before identifier error / trouble with classes

Tags: c++, string, class

Hi im learning c++ and classes. For some reason I cant some to get this specific function to run, if I comment it out everything else runs. EDIT:* I realized I didn't show proper info, but the problem isn't the case statement since even removed problem still persist. I added the whole code for card.h

*in card.h*

```
#ifndef _CARD_
#define _CARD_
#include <string>

class Card
{
    private:

        int suit;
        int rank;

    public:
        // Default Constructor
        Card();
        
        void genRandom();
        string getRank();
        string getSuit();
            void printCard();
        bool sameCard(Card);
        bool sameSuit(Card);
        bool sameRank(Card);

};

#endif
```

*in card.cpp*

```
string Card::getRank()
{
   cout << "test"; 

}
```

I'm getting errors like

> Card::getRank' : redefinition; different basic types

and

> card.h(17): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> card.h(17): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getRank'

Comment: Also on `default`, you should return a string or do something there.

Comment: `'10'` is definitely not what you want. It's a multi-character constant with an implementation-defined value. You probably want `10`, not `'10'`. I'd be surprised if your compiler didn't warn you about it.

Comment: The error message refers to `getSuit`, but you haven't shown us any code that defines, declares, or refers to `getSuit`. The problem is in some piece of code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: And you're missing a `break` after case 13.

Comment: You edited too much your question...... The replies don't fit the latest form of your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are blaming the wrong thing.  The error `C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.` is the critical part; the subsequent error is the compiler trying to make sense of the code that is already incorrect.  Always read error messages from the *top* not the *bottom*; especially when they refer to the same or adjacent lines, and fix them in that order.

The string class is in the `std::` namespace:

```
    std::string getRank();
    std::string getSuit();
```

---

```
std::string Card::getRank()
{
   std::cout << "test"; 
}
```

In your case `string` was not a type and was not followed by `()` so the compiler (looks like VC++) has assumed it was a data member, and then complained that it had no type, and that it was not followed by a `;` which is required given the earlier assumption.  The compiler also told your the error was on line 17 - so either way, you knew that was the incorrect line (although it is not always that straight forward - that is the line that the compiler stopped making sense of your code at least).

Another way to help interpret error messages is to use more than one compiler - the different diagnostics from a second compiler can often be informative.  GCC for example reports `card.h:17:9: error: ‘string’ does not name a type` - giving the line and column number (9) of the erroneous token.

Comment: Ohhh thanks alot, that was it. I always have trouble understanding the  compiler error as they seem to very ambiguous (and I suck) haha

Comment: @user2063087 : I have added further advice on error interpretation to answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `case`-s should be followed by numbers:

```
case 9: return "Nine";
case 10: return "Ten";
```

<sup>no need to `break` after a `return`!</sup>

and you should provide a default *statement*:

```
default: return "??";
```

BTW: `case '1'` is dependent on the character encoding. On my UTF-8 Linux machine, the character `1` (noted `'1'` in C or C++ code) is (encoded as) the number 49

Comment: Alternatively, `(int)'1'`, depending on the input

Comment: But characters and multicharacter litterals **are** numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:** For your latest update, the compiler cannot recognize `string`. You should use it with proper namespace, i.e. `std::`:

```
std::string getRank();
std::string getSuit();
...
std::string Card::getRank()
{
    ...
}
```

---

### ***NOTE: The followings are for the old version of OP's question.***

---

For the first error, you can NOT overload functions just based on their return values.

```
string Card::getSuit(void);
int Card::getSuit(void);
```

> #### C++11 §13.1 Overloadable declarations
>
> Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded:
>
> — **Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded**.
>
> — Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter-type-list cannot be overloaded if any of them is a static member function declaration (9.4).
>
> — [...]

---

For the second error, you should finish the `default` statement:

```
default: return "";
```

---

**P.S.:** `'10'`-`'13'` are multicharacter literals, which are implementation-defined.

> #### C++11 §2.14.3 Character literals
>
> A character literal is one or more characters enclosed in single quotes, as in `’x’`, optionally preceded by the letter `L`, as in `L’x’`. A character literal that does not begin with `L` is an ordinary character literal, also referred to as a narrow-character literal. An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char has type char, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set. **An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal has type `int` and implementation-defined value.**

Answer (score 1):

You must place a semicolon before the closing brace after label `default:`

```
default:  // <==here must be a semicolon
}
```

there must be

```
default: ;
}
```

Or simply remove this label. If the label is used then there should be a return statement because the function has return type that is not `void`.

Also these cases

```
case '10': return "Ten"; break;
case '11': return "Eleven"; break;
case '12': return "Twelve"; break;
case '13': return "Thirteen";
```

are implementation-defined becayse character literals that contain more than 1 character are implementation defined. I think that the act not as you think.

According to the C++ Standard

> An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a
>   multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary
>   character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the
>   execution character set, is conditionally-supported, **has type int, and
>   has an implementation-defined value**.

As for other error relative to function `getSuit` then the function declaration differs in two places (I think inside the class definition and outside the class definition when it was defined).